# SO_KEEPALIVE makes which connection side to send keepalive probes?

Tags: sockets, tcp

If a socket is set as `SO_KEEPALIVE` with `setsockopt`, does it means that the side which invokes `setsockopt` will send keepalive probes?

So if a side which performs the following steps, it will send keepalive probes:

1. Create a socket with `socket`
2. Use `setsockopt` to set `SO_KEEPALIVE`
3. Invoke `connect`
4. Begin data transfer

And if the other side which performs the following steps, it will also send keepalive probes:

1. Create a socket with `accept`
2. Use `setsockopt` to set `SO_KEEPALIVE`
3. Begin data transfer

I have searched on Google and browseed [TCP Keepalive HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/). But I can't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep-alive is sent from that end where the application sets the SO_KEEPALIVE on socket. When to trigger a probe on idle line, whats the interval of the probes, the count of unacknowledged probes to trigger reset - All are set as socket options which sets SO_KEEPALIVE. The peer end application does not even know the its peer is attempting keep alive.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct.  Socket option affect things only the local side can do.

If a local socket is doing keep-alive and gets no response after some retries, it will *reset*.  The other side must fend for itself.